# swf breaking bottom border when not hovered

Tags: html, css, text

the chat div is breaking the bottom of the border line when im not hovering over it. cant seem to find a solution so any help or advice? thank you.

CODE: http:/jsfiddle.net/7wf912Lt/

Comment: even after editing your question with code, it's almost impossible to understand what are you looking for and what are you talking about. What text links? Where are they?

Comment: sub is a text link, if you hover over the border line you can see it show in the bottom of the box, how Can I create 3 more div classes to be placed on each side of the border line???

Comment: where on the border line should the 3 divs be placed? just next to the edit link? (just did a fiddle and added 3 more links next to "edit" and there's no problem, so I guess you want them to show up elsewhere). would be helpful if you either describe where you want them to be or provide an image / sketch.

Comment: I want it on all 4 sides of the borderline just outside of it so I can extend it when hovered upon.

Comment: Not sure where you want them to be - inside the box, displayed in one line, with enough space to extend on hover? Just did this fiddle as base for adjustments - http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/xq9wc9dy/embedded/result/

Comment: just outside the border line, one in the middle of the left side and vice versa and just like the top and bottom as well. just like I did with my code witht the edit text link. like this http://prntscr.com/4kq96f

Comment: Im beginning to think its impossible

Comment: You mean somehow like that updated Fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/xq9wc9dy/1/embedded/result/  Just asking about the position, maybe you also want to show the top/left/right links on hover only like you did for your edit link on the bottom.

Comment: @matthias_h Thank you sir! Ill be adding you to helpers.

Comment: for info - with updating your post i meant you should keep the original post and just write at the end of the original text "update: " with a description of the current situation, *not* deleting the original post; you can just reedit the updated version of your question and add above update at the end; otherwise it could happen that the question will be closed by some reviewer as it doesn't contain enough information to qualify as question on stackoverflow

Comment: Sorry, well we getting to work or nah? we should have some other type of communication other than stack

Comment: Just wanted to know if the last fiddle worked for you or if there are still issues.

Comment: NO issues thanks, it was breaking because the divs were still there and the swf wouldn't fit so I just expanded the borderline a bit.

Answer (score 0):

As extended comments should be avoided on Stackoverflow - in case the [Fidddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/xq9wc9dy/1/embedded/result/) already looks like the required layout, just the necessary steps in case it's not so clear how it's done:

The top link is just a `<div>` on top of the embedded swf. The swf is wrapped in a `<div>` with `float:left`; the left and right link are also wrapped in a `<div>` with `float: left`. Therefore all divs are positioned in one row. To clear the float, I've just added a `<div>` with `clear:left`;. In addition, the width and height of the container have to be increased a bit so everything fits. Last step will be to reduce the `margin: left` of the container, so the content will be displayed centered. There are different solutions to display content centered, but I guess you'll have no problem to fix the rest.
For the Fiddle I just increased the height of .chat to 550px, the extra 50px are needed to have the additional height for the top link. Otherwise the swf would be displayed breaking the bottom border / partly outside of the box.

Update: Question was changed from displaying links around an embedded swf (which is solved) into the follow-up issue that the swf breaks the bottom border when it's not hovered. Problem is that link provided in question doesn't display the swf chat, therefore the mentioned problem is not solvable. Already added the CodePen-CSS into an updated Fiddle and only changed the height of .chat from 500px into 550px to provide enough space for the added links, and swf doesn't display like described. Further information to be added to the question is from which browser the screenshot was taken as I've only tested with Firefox and there it displays as intended.

Update2: As updated Fiddle by OP displays the described problem, should be fixable by adjusting css. The problem is located in the left link with the position set to 200px; if set to 0 before hover, the chat is displayed in the border when the height is set to 550px instead of 500px.

Update 3: Adjusted Fiddle like follows: changed the left link to `position: absolute;`, so it's taken out of the flow and won't interfere with the chat window. Otherwise the chat would be pushed down on hover when the left link is displayed on hovering chat as both share the same position for some seconds. Also reduced the margin-left of the chat so it's displayed centered. Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/2586g9yb/9/embedded/result/)
I guess you won't have any problems to e.g. adjust the padding or margins if you want more or less distance between the links and the border.
In case this works as intended would be kind to follow this step - [Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , otherwise just add possible issues to your question.

Comment: Well I fixed some stuff to make it how the way I wanted ti to be, but the swf is lower and goes off the box unless the borderline is hovered upon, any help? thank btw ur awesome. CODE : http://codepen.io/Apoph1s/pen/LrqFa

Comment: @KareemEllaisy np, just updated my answer. In your codepen the .chat still has the 500px height, I already adjusted that in my fiddle to 550px but that's in the middle of the css, so it's maybe a bit hidden.

Comment: the 550px increase the bottom of the borderline, which reminds me to ask you how you can increase on the opposite side? and the chat still breaks the bottom when the border line is not hovered upon

Comment: minor problem is that the swf isn't displayed in your codepen and the chat doesn't break the border in my fiddle - so it should be possible do be done, I just don't know yet where's the difference between your code and my fiddle. with "increasing on the opposite side" you mean how to get some more place between the top link and the upper border?

Comment: I put my code into the fiddle: http://prntscr.com/4l1pcn AFTER HOVERING: http://prntscr.com/4l1pjs

Comment: strange.. just copied your css in my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/xq9wc9dy/2/embedded/result/  and won't break, only diff is that I have 550px height instead of 500px for .chat

Comment: will have a look at that tomorrow as it's very late here, guess we're in diff timezones. maybe you'll have already figured it out until then, shouldn't be too much left to be done. possibly it has either something to be done with the float after hover or with the position: relative of the left / right links. and mention the browser you're on, I'm on firefox, possibly it's a browser issue fixable with diff css.

Comment: The difference is that in the html part, I deleted the width of being 850px, when it hovered the borderline is 850, when its not hovered it 700. that's why

Comment: Okay just acknowledge what I said before this comment, then we will continue this lol.

Comment: back for while. Still problems with the chat breaking the border? And you should try to update your post describing how it's currently displayed because extended comments on stackoverflow may result in being moved into stackoverflow chat (which isn't working for you because you need 20 reputation to access)

Comment: Yeah check what I said like 3 comments ago.